# Yii2. dektrium/user. Custom controller action redirects to the login page

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

**Problem**

Every custom action redirects back to the login page.

**My code**

I've extended my custom controller from the `dektrium\user\controllers\RegistrationController`

My `web.php`

```
 'urlManager'   => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName'  => false,
            'rules'           => [

            ],
        ],
```

...

```
'modules'    => [
        'user' => [
            'class'         => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'controllerMap' => [
                'registration' => 'app\controllers\user\RegistrationController'
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Custom controller

```
namespace app\controllers\user;

use dektrium\user\controllers\RegistrationController as BaseAdminController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseAdminController
{
    public function actionPlan()
    {
        echo 'Test';
    }
}
```

Overrode methods works good, but each custom action (`site.com/user/registration/plan`) redirects back to the login page.

Comment: are you logged?

Comment: @scaisEdge no. //just characters to be at least 15 chara...

Comment: with dektrium  if you are not  logged  you are automcatically redirect to login  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge is it possible to avoid it? I have to make multi-page registration, so there should be the first one with prices.

Comment: I have posted an answer  hope is what you are looking for

Comment: @scaisEdge could you check my answer? Is it a better way to implement?

Comment: Your answer is right but it is just a refinement of my .. I have not entered into much detail because the goal was to suggest the road .. so ... ...

Comment: @scaisEdge of course) I just want to make as good, as I can. Is my implementation better (I suppose it's more flexible)? (Just a gap between the upwote and acception)

Comment: You implementantion is different and is related to  your need .. for me the absence of the part related to the action allowed for logged user is not good .. you should ever mantain a clear vision or the access permission .. inside the controller ..

Comment: @scaisEdge thank you for the answer. I'll rely on your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want change  the access control rules  you should change properly eg: in your site controller  add  plan to the rules  accessible without authenctication

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
   public function behaviors()
   {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login','plan',  'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

see this for more  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
   public function behaviors()
   {
    $behaviors = [
        'access' => [
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'plan', 'error'],
                    'allow'   => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return ArrayHelper::merge($behaviors, parent::behaviors());
    }
}
```